# Password input element removes rows from a table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've got this problem, I'm working with C# and MVC architecture. there is a view where it shows multiple rows in a table. In the other hand, I've got a modal popup where there is a form for user maintenance, then when I click on any place on the view the rows from the table disappears. I thought it was a javascript or something, but searching for all over the views and modals I realized that when I comment the password input element the problem fix. so I was wondering what could it be, because there is no javascript assigned to the password input element or to the modal. for more detail this is my code.

html table:

```
          <table id="tbSistema" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Asignar</th>
                        <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
                        <th>Número Parte</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Marca</th>
                        <th>Tiempo</th>
                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbodyGaranVenta">


                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="~/Content/img/icons/Select.png" 
                        onclick="AsignarPeriGarant('@item.Codigo')" /> </td>
                        <td>@item.FechaIngreso</td>
                        <td>@item.NumParte</td>
                        <td>@item.Equipo</td>
                        <td>@item.Marca</td>
                        <td>@item.Tiempo</td>
                        <td>@item.Comentario</td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

         $('#tbSistema').DataTable({
            language: {
                "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "sUrl": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast": "Último",
                    "sNext": "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            }
        });
```

modal code:

```
<div class="popup" id="modalMantUsuario">
<div class="modal-body" id="popup">
    <a href="#" class="close" onclick="">x</a>
    <div class="titulo">
        <a>Usuarios</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__wrapper">
            <div class="card__content">
                <div class="form">
                    <ul class="form__list">
                        <li class="form__item">
                            <label class="form__label form__label__short">Usuario</label>
                            <input id="txtUsuarioMdlUsuario" type="text" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="form__item" id="liPerfil">
                            <label class="form__label form__label__short">Perfil</label>
                            <select id="cboxPerfilMdlUsuario"> 
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <span class="separator"></span>
                        <li class="form__item">
                            <label class="form__label form__label__short">Password</label>
                            <input id="txtPasswordMdlUsuario" type="password"  />
                        </li>
                        <li class="form__item">
                            <label class="form__label form__label__short">Repetir Password</label>
                            <input id="txtRepPasswordMdlUsuario" type="password" />
                        </li>                            
                        <span class="separator"></span>
                        <li class="form__item">
                            <div style="display:flex">
                                <label for="ckboxEstadoMdlUsuario" >Activo</label>
                                <input id="ckboxEstadoMdlUsuario" name="ckboxEstadoMdlUsuario" 
                                type="checkbox" />
                            </div>                               
                        </li>
                        <li class="form__item">
                            <label class="form__label form__label__short">Impresora</label>
                            <select id="cboxImpresoraMdlUsuario">
                                <option value="0">Seleccione Impresora</option>
                                <option value="1">ZDesigner TLP 2844 ETIQUETAS</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <span class="separator"></span>
                        <li class="form__item">
                            <div style="display:flex">
                                <a class="button button_blue" onclick="">Guardar</a>
                                <a class="button button_orange" onclick="">Cancelar</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove datatable script from your view and check if this is related with datatable javascript.

Comment: Where you put the modal?When you  `click on any place on the view`,will you see any new request？

Comment: thanks for your help, well I had the modal on the layout page, I decided to move it into the view where it is called.so the problem was solved but I still dont understand why the input password generates that problem since I have several modal in the layout page and only happens with that modal.